# Integer induction without infinity

Tags: logic, set-theory, induction, foundations, incompleteness

In ZFC minus infinity (let us call this T), one can still define ordinals, and
then define integers as ordinals all of whose members are zero or successor
ordinals.

I am looking for a formula $\psi$ such that

- T proves $\psi(0)$
- T proves $\psi(n)\Rightarrow \psi(n+1)$ for every "integer" (in the above sense ) $n$,
- T does not prove the (obviously true) $\forall \ \text{integer}\ n, \psi(n)$.

This would be a typical situation of $\omega$-incompleteness. This is probably 
well-known, but I cannot remember where it is explained.

Comment: You may be interested in these axioms for the integers: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279111/do-these-axioms-fully-describe-the-integers/311280#311280

Comment: The "obviously true" statement is either not obviously true (if "integer" is interpreted in $T$) or is not a statement of $T$ (if "integer" is interpreted in the meta-theory).  There is a more important preliminary issue: $T$ does have any closed terms, so it is not trivial to even *express* $\psi(n)$ for a finite ordinal $n$. In particular one cannot do that by just replacing the free variable of $\psi(x)$ with some term for $n$. This is different from Peano arithmetic, where each natural number has a canonical term of the form $1 + 1 + \cdots + 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\psi$ is such formula, and let $(M,E)$ be a model of $T$ in which $\forall n(n\text{ is an integer}\rightarrow\psi(n))$ is false.

Consider $A=\{k\mid M\models\lnot\psi(k)\land k\text{ is an integer}\}$, then this class cannot have an $E$-minimal element. If $M\models k=\min A$, then of course $k\neq 0$, since $T\vdash\varphi(0)$, so $k=n+1$, but $M\models\psi(n)\land(\psi(n)\rightarrow\psi(n+1))$, so $M\models\psi(k)$.

Therefore $A$ is a class without a least element. This is a contradiction, since if $M\models k\in A$, then $M\models k\cap A\text{ is a set linearly ordered by }E\text{ and without a least element}$, which is a contradiction to the fact that $M$ satisfies the axiom of foundation.

---

Note that the assumption that $T\vdash\psi(0)\land\forall k(k\text{ is an integer}\land\psi(k)\rightarrow\psi(k+1))$ was necessary here.

On the other hand, if you only require that $T$ proves this for meta-integers, then something like $n$ encodes a proof for contradiction from $T$ is an example for a statement like that.

Comment: I don't quite follow your third paragraph. I agree that $A$ has been shown to be a class without a least element. But I fail to see how you deduce a contradiction from this. How do you find a $k$ such that $M\models k\in A$ ? $M$ satisfies the axiom of foundation for its sets, it does not necessarily satisfy it for its classes.

Comment: Do you agree that $M$ satisfies that $A$ is not empty?

Comment: Ah yes, that’s because we chose $M$ so that $\forall n \psi(n)$ is false ...

Comment: Good. Now take any $k\in A$. So $M\models\lnot\psi(k)$. Now consider $x$ such that $M\models y\in x\leftrightarrow y\in k\land\lnot\psi(y)$. By the fact $M$ satisfies the separation schema, $x$ is a unique set which exists in $M$. Now show that $x$ is a linearly ordered set without a least element.

Comment: Is the axiom of foundation essential here?

Comment: @Rob: Probably not, since we explicitly define integers as ordinals, so it is a subset of an ordinal without a least element, which is impossible.