# Defining integer sum without using infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, foundations

In ZFC minus infinity (let us call this system $T$), one can still define ordinals, and
then define integers as ordinals all of whose members are zero or successor
ordinals. Combining the power set axiom with the subset axiom scheme, one
can also define the cartesian product of two sets (using the Kuratowski pair
$(a,b)=\lbrace \lbrace a \rbrace, \lbrace a,b \rbrace \rbrace$, $A\times B$
is a subset of ${\cal P}({\cal P}(A\cup B))$).

Consider the statement $\phi$ to the effect that if $\alpha,\beta$ are
any two integers (in the above sense) then there is another integer $\gamma$
such that there is a bijection between 
$(\lbrace 0 \rbrace \times \alpha) \cup (\lbrace 1 \rbrace \times \beta)$
and $\gamma$.

Then $\phi$ is true and can be proven (outside $T$) by induction. It follows
from the argument in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224128/integer-induction-without-infinity) by Asaf Karagila that $\phi$ is in fact
already provable inside $T$.

But notice that Asaf's argument is rather advanced (it uses for example
Gödel's "completeness theorem" that every consistent theory has a model) and
indirect : it shows that there is an elementary proof inside $T$ without
explicitly giving it.

My question is, describe explicitly a completely elementary proof of $\phi$
from $T$.

Comment: May I assume that you know how to prove $\phi$ in ZFC? Where does your proof use the axiom of infinity?

Comment: @RobArthan $\phi$ is obvious in ZFC : in this case $\gamma$ is just $\alpha+\beta$. The axiom of infinity is used in the induction, which presuppose the existence of $\omega$

Comment: transfinite induction doesn't need the axiom of infinity.

Comment: Transfinite induction only appeals the infinity when you want to claim the "transfinite" part is not trivial. But as a theorem itself it's quite doable. As for my answer, using the completeness theorem is in fact the sensible thing to do here, in the sense that it doesn't require you to meddle with syntactic proofs which are always harder than just proofs. You can transform everything in my answer to a direct proof, then apply to to the suggest $\phi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just use replacement? Let $S$ be the well order consisting of $\alpha$ followed by $\beta$, as in the question.

Proof sketch: Consider the collection $C$ of all ordinals $x$ such that there is a (necessarily unique) order isomorphism $f_x$ between $x$ and a (necessarily unique) initial segment of $S$. By replacement $C$ is a set. Then $\bigcup C$ is an ordinal, and $\bigcup_{x \in C} f_x$ is a bijection from $L$ to $\bigcup C$.

I don't see any use of the axiom of infinity there.